# What is the difference between JAX, Trax, and TensorRT, in simple terms?

Tags: tensorflow, jax, trax

I have been using TensorRT and TensorFlow-TRT to accelerate the inference of my DL algorithms.

Then I have heard of:

- JAX https://github.com/google/jax
- Trax https://github.com/google/trax

Both seem to accelerate DL. But I am having a hard time to understand them. Can anyone explain them in simple terms?

Comment: Related thread at Data Science SE: [What is the difference between Trax and Tensorflow?](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/87841/what-is-the-difference-between-trax-and-tensorflow)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Trax` is a deep learning framework created by Google and extensively used by the Google Brain team. It comes as an alternative to `TensorFlow` and `PyTorch` when it comes to implementing off-the-shelf state of the art deep learning models, for example Transformers, Bert etc. , in principle with respect to the Natural Language Processing field.

`Trax` is built upon `TensorFlow` and `JAX`. `JAX` is an enhanced and optimised version of Numpy. The important distinction about `JAX` and `NumPy` is that the former using a library called XLA (advanced linear algebra) which allows to run your `NumPy` code on `GPU` and `TPU` rather than on `CPU` like it happens in the plain `NumPy`, thus speeding up computation.